# How to use Python Dbus bindings in Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, dbus

I am trying to install dbus on Anaconda python environment and I am struggling.

Here is the error message I am getting:

```
e@gateway:~$ python
Python 3.5.4 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 11:22:58) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ImportError: /home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
>>>
```

Here are some of the outputs I think may be asked:

```
e@gateway:~$ conda install dbus
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/e/anaconda3:
#
dbus                      1.10.22              h3b5a359_0  


e@gateway:~$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev libdbus-1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdbus-glib-1-dev is already the newest version (0.106-1).
libdbus-1-dev is already the newest version (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


e@gateway:~$ sudo apt-get install dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dbus is already the newest version (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


e@gateway:~$ which python
/home/e/anaconda3/bin/python


e@gateway:~$ conda --version
conda 4.3.31

e@gateway:~$ sudo /home/e/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install dbus-python
The directory '/home/e/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/e/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: dbus-python in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

DBus is working fine on the system python, however not working on Anaconda Python.

Python 2.7:

```
e@gateway:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
e@gateway:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
>>>
```

Python 3.5:

```
e@gateway:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
e@gateway:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbus
>>>
```

Can anyone help me? Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, there are few cases where dbus and python [don't work well out-of-the-box](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring#linux). The consensus appears to be that you need a system-level install (i.e. `apt-get`) to get dbus to work. I believe the `/home/e/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_dbus_bindings.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct` error you're seeing is directly related to that.

`conda install dbus` does not add anything to `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`, but instead appears to install some executables in `~/anaconda3/bin/` like `dbus-run-session`, `dbus-daemon`, etc. This makes some sense when you analyze the contents of the dbus tarball https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dbus, as it's all C files and executables. I'm not sure it's supposed to be the `dbus` python module, but I could be wrong.

EDIT:

I searched the conda repositories and found a few individuals that uploaded a version of dbus-python, presumably that they compiled and installed. I tried [this one](https://anaconda.org/scottwales/dbus-python) out in a py3.6 conda environment via:

`conda install -c scottwales dbus-python`

I was then able to import dbus. This is a hacky approach and should not be used in production, I'd recommend listening to 
Carlos Cordoba's post below. But if you need a solution now, search through some user conda packages or try to compile the library yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone help me? Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Yes, you are. There's one thing people still don't understand about `conda`: `conda` is **not** a `pip` replacement. It is a general package manager, in the same vein as `apt-get`, `yum`, `brew`, `emerge`, etc, but cross-platform and based on Python.

In this case, that means that `conda install dbus` does not install the Python Dbus bindings, as you would expect with `pip` . It installs the Dbus C package itself, which is needed by Qt 5 (again, the C++ library, not the Python bindings to it).

Unfortunately, there are no Conda packages for [`dbus-python`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbus-python). To make matters worse, it seems there's no easy way to create packages for it, as pointed out [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/2251).

Finally, you said

> Here is the error message I am getting

The (most probable) cause of that error is because you added your system Python `dist-packages` path to the `PYTHONPATH` of Anaconda or because you blindly copied the `dbus` module from system Python to Anaconda. Please don't do that ever again. System Python and Anaconda packages are compiled with different compilers and under different conditions. So mixing them is the cause of incomprehensible errors, just like the one you reported.