# Anaconda / Spyder new package?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to install ffmpeg on my Anaconda/Spyder install (Win 10/64 bit). I have it in Anaconda

[image: Anaconda]

However, Spyder does not recognize it

```
import matplotlib.animation as ani

ani.MovieWriterRegistry().list()
[]

import ffmpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-16f5f3b4de71>", line 1, in <module>
    import ffmpeg

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ffmpeg'
```

Am I missing a step? I'm obviously rather new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which of the several [Python bindings for ffmpeg](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ffmpeg&submit=search) are you actually trying to use? If the answer is 'don't know', you have some reading up to do first.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is caused by the common confusion `conda is a pip replacement`, which is false.

Basically, conda installed for you the ffmpeg C library, not the Python bindings to it.

I have given answers at length about this topic, so I don't plan to do it again. Please see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160569/438386) for example.